# Style is not rendering in button when using in ASP.Net MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, stylesheet

In my project Button click action is not rendering as per the style provided So i tried two methods and both have screenshots attached.

```
1.<button type="submit" class = "btn btn-success">@Html.ActionLink("Save", "EmployeeRegistration",
"Home")</button> 
2.<button type="submit" >@Html.ActionLink("Save", "EmployeeRegistration", "Home",new{@class = "btn
     btn-success"})</button>
```

both have Style Issues
[image: ScreenShot for Method1]

[image: Screenshot for Method2]

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for a try, see what output the next line gives to you :-

```
<input type="submit" class = "btn btn-success" value="Save" />
```

Use only this :-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "EmployeeRegistration", "Home", new{ @class = "btn
 btn-success"});
```

You were using Hyperlink within a button, that's why your button was dis aligned.

Use this style :-

```
.btn {
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.428571429;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: When am using the above code Its working but the button text is not visible that means its not rendering as per the style.Thats problem

Comment: Add the CSS class in your stylesheet.

Comment: its already there...all css styles are loaded in the Layout page

Comment: that means your styles are overriding each other. you can find this by inspect element. Some `a` style is overriding your `.btn` class.

Comment: <input type="submit" class = "btn btn-success" value="Save" /> This one works Fine.Updated the Action name and Controller name like this...@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeRegistration", "Home",FormMethod.Post))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save", "EmployeeRegistration", "Home", new{ }, new{@class = "btn
     btn-success"})
```